# Return the converted SOAP/XML object to url

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I have program for parsing SOAP object using java. But it not possible to return the parsed SOAP object. And how to pass that on url.
my program is,

```
   public class MarshalDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.id = 123;
    customer.firstName = "Jane";
    customer.lastName = "Doe";
    QName root = new QName("return");
    JAXBElement<Customer> je = new JAXBElement<Customer>(root, Customer.class, customer);

    XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLStreamWriter xsw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
    xsw.writeStartDocument();
    xsw.writeStartElement("S", "Envelope", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    xsw.writeStartElement("S", "Body", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    xsw.writeStartElement("ns0", "findCustomerResponse", "http://service.jaxws.blog/");

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(je, xsw);

    xsw.writeEndDocument();
    xsw.close();
  }
 }

 class Customer {
   int id;
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to leverage JAX-WS to create a Web Service.  Your service class will look something like the following.   JAX-WS will take care of creating the `Envelope` and `Body` elements as well as sending the data over the wire.  JAX-WS leverages JAXB as the object-to-XML layer so you just need to add any necessary JAXB annotations to your `Customer` class and JAX-WS will automatically add it to the message for you.

```
import javax.jws.*;

@WebService
public class FindCustomer {

 @WebMethod
 public Customer findCustomer(int id) {
  Customer customer = new Customer();
  customer.setId(id);
  customer.setFirstName("Jane");
  customer.setLastName("Doe");
  return customer;
 }

}
```

Comment: sorry, i can't understand what you say. how to return the converted SOAP object to url

Comment: How do you plan to run your Web Service?  I'm assuming you will be using an application server such as GlassFish, WebLogic, WebSphere, etc

Comment: i'm using a spring tool and its for payment process. i want to forward the converted `SOAP` into url using `POST` method. it return some `SOAP` object. then i parse to String and use in my program